# R xgboost importance plot with many features

Tags: r, ggplot2, xgboost, kaggle

I am trying out the Kaggle housing prices challenge : https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques

Here is the script I wrote

```
train    <- read.csv("train.csv")
train$Id <- NULL
previous_na_action = options('na.action')
options(na.action = 'na.pass')
sparse_matrix <- sparse.model.matrix(SalePrice~.-1,data = train)
options(na.action = previous_na_action)
model <- xgboost(data = sparse_matrix, label = train$SalePrice, missing = NA, max.depth = 6, eta = 0.3, nthread = 4, nrounds = 16, verbose = 2, objective = "reg:linear")
importance <- xgb.importance(feature_names = sparse_matrix@Dimnames[[2]], model = model)
print(xgb.plot.importance(importance_matrix = importance))
```

The data has over 70 features, I used `xgboost` with `max.depth` = 6 and `nrounds` = 16.

The importance plot i am getting is very messed up, how do i get to view only the top 5 features or something.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the `top_n` argument to `xgb.plot.importance`. It does exactly what you want.

```
# Plot only top 5 most important variables.
print(xgb.plot.importance(importance_matrix = importance, top_n = 5))
```

Edit: only on development version of xgboost. Alternative method is to do this:

```
print(xgb.plot.importance(importance_matrix = importance[1:5]))
```

Comment: Which version are you using i am getting error unused argument top_n = 5?

Comment: Looks like they added it recently, the CRAN version doesn't have it. If you want to get the most up-to-date version, [install from their github repository](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/R-package). I'll edit my answer to have an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
xgbImp1 <- xgb.importance(model = model)
```

This will identify the important features of your model.

```
xgbImp1 <- xgbImp1 %>% mutate(rank = dense_rank(desc(Gain)))
```

This will provide a rank to each of the feature so we can change it to top 5,10,15 and 20.

```
ggplot(data=xgbImp1[which(xgbImp1$rank <= 20),], aes(x = reorder(Feature, -Gain), y = Gain)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(title = "XG Boosted Feature Importance (Top 20)", x = "Features", y = "Information Gain")
```